# Dots placing incorrectly in multiple language document

Tags: adobe-indesign, typefaces

I'm translating a book from English to Persian where some of the words need to still be in English and it's a mix of Right to Left and Left to Right reading directions.

my language is persian and

Persian reads Right to Left, which is fine, but whenever I use dots in my translation it shows up like this:

[image]

This is incorrect, the first dot should be before the min like so:

[image]

Testing in Microsoft Office Word  it works correctly but in Adobe InDesign 2017 it is wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using InDesign ME version? is your text set to RTL? have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

My mother Language is *Persian* and this is a problem for huge number of people who use *Adobe's* products, and when they had to have or type context with a mix of two languages with different writing systems. it could be annoying and waste time to correct and modify those texts.

Personally I type or import my Persian body text with a mix of two languages (one of them; RTL to LTR [in my case, Persian] and the other one; LTR to RTL (English or any Latin Languages). My Persian body text uses paragraph style(s) [one or more]. Then create *character style(s)* for those Latin texts that go between my Persian lines and text. I apply *character style(s)* to Latin text/languages and now they are correct as I wish and expect, even if they have similar texts like an extension with a point: *.min.js* or whatever like this.

Note that when we have an RTL language like Persian, it's naturally we use and create RTL styles and direction, but for Latin, languages are vice-versa. So we create character style(s) for in-line texts, you should choose "**Left-to-Right option** from "**Character Direction**" drop-menu of "**Character Style Options**" window.

[image]

If you have a few of these Latin language texts like the extension with points you mentioned, you can select those extensions (Latin texts) one by one by **Text Tool [T]** and apply your *character style* to them. 
If you have many, use **Find/Replace** feature with more powerful options to find and apply your specific *character style(s)* that created for those specific Latin texts that are located between an RTL language.

In this way, you can find and replace those incorrect extensions or whatever with the correct ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I use a temporary psd or Ai translator. Search for arabic psd converter. When i encounter this, one even if I am in arabic mode in language. The illustrator or Indesign type tool always write from left to right. Then I search for the solution and this psd text works. First I let the arabic customers to type then highlight the text (in psd) then open a new file in ai choose text then paste then if dots are not in proper place i expand the text then position it. For you case outline also and link to in design. the only problem is positioning.